# Inline assembler for ARM : Error

Tags: c, inline-assembly

Optimizing a code using inline assembler feature,but when i insert a inline in my code getting following error!!! someone please let me know where i'm doing mistake??
It will be useful,thank you in advance.

calcexc.c:119: error: expected string literal before '[' token

#if 1

__asm("SMLA  %[Rd], %[Rm], %[Rs], %[Rn]"

```
                :[Rd] "=r" (L_acc)
                :[Rn] "+r" (L_acc)
                :[Rm] "r"  (temp1), [Rs] "r"  (temp1));
```

#else

```
    L_acc = (L_acc + ((temp1*temp1)<<1));
```

#endif

--
Chethan

Comment: When using gcc's inline asm, the first parameter after the colon is a comma delimited list of outputs, after the second colon is a comma delimited set of inputs, after the third is the list of clobbered registers (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).  What are you doing that you list L_acc twice like this?  Which are your input parameters and which are your outputs?

Comment: Actually L_acc is input as well as output,you can observe "#else statement" in above code. What i understand is "=r" for overwrite on a register and "+r" for input/output.Am i correct??

Comment: 3 points: 1) A single variable can't be both "output only" and "input+output."  It must be one or the other.  2) "+r" is still an output, so it must be listed with the outputs (ie after the first colon, not the second).  3) As I stated before, after the first colon is all outputs (both output only and input/output).  After the second colon is input-only parameters.  What do you think you are putting after the third colon?  It's supposed to be clobbers, but that's not how clobbers work.

Comment: That was great explanation Mr.David :) In that case could you please modify my code. I'm newbie to assembly code.

Comment: Ok, I (sort of) see what you are doing.  I am not familiar with SMLA.  What platform is that from?  ARM?  Maybe you could try something like `__asm("SMLA %[Rd], %[Rm], %[Rm], %[Rd]" :[Rd] "+r" (L_acc) :[Rm] "r"  (temp1));`.

Comment: Yeah ARM only, let me explain SMLA instruction,it is an opcode do the signed multiplication + addition, what we call in general term MAC in dsp,so an single instruction do so much operations.SMLA with operands called Rd,Rm,Rs and Rn. Here Rd is destination Rm*Rs+Rn. :) This is my motive in the code

Comment: Ahh, there's ARM right in your title.  Sorry about that.  What happened with the sample I suggested?

Comment: Sorry,since your modified code asking rest of the operands (Rs and Rm)

Comment: How can it be asking for Rs?  There is no Rs in my sample?  Also, I'm trying to read about ARM SMLA and I'm not finding it.  I see SMLAD, SMLA<x><y>, etc on http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/Cihbdgie.html.  Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Yes,your in the right place,their you can observe SLMAxy with four operands,so need to take care of all four operands.Ignore <x><y> append with the instruction.

Comment: My sample does have 4 operands.  It uses Rd and Rm twice each, but doesn't even list Rs so how can it give an error?  Did you leave some of your old code there?  Here's the code I'm suggesting: `__asm("SMLA %[Rd], %[Rm], %[Rm], %[Rd]" :[Rd] "+r" (L_acc) :[Rm] "r" (temp1));`.

Comment: Compile error:                                                                                             /tmp/cc7Gmd9U.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc7Gmd9U.s:352: Error: bad instruction `smla ip,r0,r0,ip'
make: *** [calcexc.o] Error 1

Comment: As my opinion on your code,you made code as smart way by using only two operands but it suppose to have output operand like "=r". What you say???

Comment: Well, at least we have fixed the "expected string literal" error.  This new error is coming from the assembler.  It says "smla" isn't a valid instruction.  You told me to ignore <x><y>, but that page I linked to says that you must put something after smla, like smlabb.  I don't speak ARM, so I don't know how to help you fix that.

Comment: Using "=r" means that you are writing to the variable.  Using "+r" means that you are both reading and writing the variable.  Looking at your C code, `L_acc = (L_acc + ...`, you ARE reading and writing L_acc.  However, if it makes you feel better, try `__asm("SMLA %[Rd], %[Rn], %[Rm], %[Ra]" :[Rd] "=r" (L_acc) : [Ra] "r" (L_acc), [Rm] "r" (temp1), [Rn] "r" (temp1));`.  Note that you still have the fix the SMLA thing.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi david,thanks for your patience.based on your reviews and suggestions i'm very close to the bug fixing.I will update shortly where i'm doing mistake.